# An error in Gravitation by Misner Thorne and Wheeler?

Tags: general-relativity, textbook-erratum

I was studying on Gravitation the PPN formalism.

Since in equation (39.41) pag. 1087, the term

$1 + \dfrac{v^2}{2}+(2+\gamma)U = 1 + \dfrac{v^2}{2}+3U$ (the second in GR)

looked odd, I tried (several times) to derive the formula, but I always find:

$1 + \dfrac{v^2}{2}+U$

Is this one of the two famous errors metioned by Wheeler?

I am really going crazy over this...

Comment: Just two errors? I find that unlikely.

Comment: Just two *famous* ones...

Comment: Is the question really to know if this is specifically one of two mentioned by Wheeler, or just if this is an error?

Comment: @Brick just to know if it is an error.

Comment: In the edition that I have, I have the equation $A^0{}_0 = 1 + \frac{v^2}{2} + U + {\cal O} (\epsilon^4)$. Is this the one that you are looking for?

Comment: Your question is confusing because 39.41 includes several equations, some of which have the $2+\gamma$ and some of which don't.  Which one do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equation 39.41 is quite different in my edition:

$$ A^0_0 = 1 + \frac{v^2}{2} + U + O(\epsilon^4) $$

This is from the hardcover edition published 12/31/1973 (ISBN 0-7167-0334-3). Prior to this the paperback version was published 9/15/1973 (ISBN 0-7167-0334-1).

If your edition has an ISBN number ending in 1 or 2, then this is the revised and correct equation.

Comment: Yes you are right: I have the second edition.